# Sort dates that span between months without year in Python

Tags: python

is there any concise way to sort days that span between months or even different years in python? For example, this list which starts from Dec 23rd to January 8th of the following year:

```
[
( 1,  1),
( 1,  2),
( 1,  3),
( 1,  4),
( 1,  5),
( 1,  6),
( 1,  7),
( 1,  8),
(12, 23),
(12, 24),
(12, 25),
(12, 26),
(12, 27),
(12, 28),
(12, 29),
(12, 30),
(12, 31)
]
```

Comment: Are you expecting (12,31) to come before (1,1)? How can you tell that without the year? What's the general rule that decides if (x,y) comes before or after (z,w)?

Comment: without the year, how do you know 12/31 comes before 1/1?

Comment: @Orius, I know because these dates come from a `groupby` function of Pandas. There are certain things that happen in these dates every year and I group them to deduct daily statistics. So, for example, (12, 23) is a key to the minimum value of all the values that happen in Dec 23rd of the last 10 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the year column too in the list. If the year is added at index `2`,you can use sort function in this way:

```
x=[
( 1,  1,2018),
( 1,  2,2018),
( 1,  3,2018),
( 1,  4,2018),
( 1,  5,2018),
( 1,  6,2018),
( 1,  7,2018),
( 1,  8,2018),
(12, 23,2017),
(12, 24,2017),
(12, 25,2017),
(12, 26,2017),]
x.sort(lambda i:[i[2],i[0],[1]])
```

It sorts in the order of Year,month and date

Comment: That's the problem. I can't.

Comment: It seems that I don't have any other way but to add "fake" years and remove them later. So, I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other answers, you need year to sort the dates.

Here is another way you can do using datetime module:

```
import datetime
date_list = [( 1,  1), ...]
date_list = [datetime.date(month=date[0], day=date[1], year=2012) for date in date_list]
date_list.sort()
```